# Why can't Houou tell that Hinako isn't actually his brother?

Tags: kenka-banchou-otome

The basic premise of *Kenka Banchou Otome* (the anime, anyway) is that Onigashima Hikaru (a boy) and Nakayama Hinako (a girl) swap places, resulting in Hinako attending Shishiku Academy (a boy's school) while disguied as Hikaru.

Most of the main cast has never actually met the real Onigashima Hikaru prior to the swap, and both Hikaru and Hinako are sort of androgynous, so the deception works.

But Hikaru's elder brother Houou also attends Shishiku Academy, and encounters Hinako (in the guise of Hikaru) multiple times, starting in episode 9. For some reason, the disguise fools Houou as well - he shows no signs of being aware that the person he's speaking with is not actually his brother Hikaru.

Is there a reason that Houou is also fooled by Hinako's disguise (other than "the plot demands it")? We can infer, based on their conversation in episode 9, that Houou and the real Hikaru have met before (they weren't raised separately or whatnot), so this is rather odd.

Comment: Does it fool him? Or is he just playing cool and letting his imouto have fun? (adn probably making his job easier by beating up those dead weighs) I think that if he didn't know, by the time when she cals him onii-chan it was a dead giveaway. I haven't played the game, but I think he is just indulging Hikaru in his swapper. Also, that wig. Also, that shirtless macho bravado.

Answer (score 1):

Since every episode of the anime is very short, a lot of details are left out. In the game it is mentioned by others and Houou himself that although they are brothers, they don't live together and didn't see each other much.